# why can i free a part of a struct it free all the struct

Tags: c, pointers, testing, struct, free

Hi I need to write a function free to the key element of a map and free to the data element of the map.

I defined two struct obviously with their typedef:

```
struct player_stats
{
    int player_id;
    Player_data data_of_player;
    Player_stats next;
};

struct player_data
{
    int number_of_wins;
    int number_of_losses;
    int number_of_equals;
};
```

the problem is the creation of the function freePlayerKey:
I need to write a function that do free to the int player_id.
i tried this ,it 's working but oddly it also do free to the player_data

```
void freePlayerId (void* player_id_to_free)
{
    free(player_id_to_free);
}
```

for example I wrote a little test:

```
doron->player_id=10;
doron->data_of_player->number_of_wins=20
freePlayerId(&(doron->player_id));
printf("%d\n",doron->player_id);
printf("%d\n",doron->data_of_player->number_of_wins);
```

i expect that it will be
number not defined
20
but it does:
number not defined
number not defined

complete code here

```
void* copyPlayerId (void* player_id_to_copy)
{
    if(player_id_to_copy==NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    int* id_copied = malloc(sizeof(*id_copied));
    if(id_copied==NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    *id_copied=*(int*)player_id_to_copy;
    return (void*) id_copied;
}

void* copyDataPlayer (void* player_data_to_copy)
{
    if(player_data_to_copy==NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    Player_data new_copy=malloc(sizeof(*new_copy));
    if(new_copy==NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    new_copy->number_of_wins=(*(Player_data *)player_data_to_copy)->number_of_wins;
    new_copy->number_of_equals=(*(Player_data *)player_data_to_copy)->number_of_equals;
    new_copy->number_of_losses=(*(Player_data *)player_data_to_copy)->number_of_losses;
    return (void*) new_copy;
}

void freePlayerId (void* player_id_to_free)
{
     free(player_id_to_free);
}

void freeDataPlayer(void* player_data_to_free)
{
    Player_data to_free=*(Player_data*) player_data_to_free;
    free(&(to_free->number_of_wins));
    free(&(to_free->number_of_equals));
    free(&(to_free->number_of_losses));
    free(player_data_to_free);
}

struct player_stats
{
    int player_id;
    Player_data data_of_player;
    Player_stats next;
};

struct player_data
{
    int number_of_wins;
    int number_of_losses;
    int number_of_equals;
};


   int main()
{
    Map player=createPlayerMap();
    Player_stats doron=malloc(sizeof (*doron));
    if(doron==NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    Player_data new_data=malloc(sizeof (*new_data));
    new_data->number_of_equals=3;
    new_data->number_of_losses=0;
    new_data->number_of_wins=20;
    doron->player_id=346267420;
    doron->next=NULL;
    doron->data_of_player=new_data;

    //insert doron in the map
    mapPut(player,&doron->player_id,&doron->data_of_player);

    //create a copy
    Player_stats doron_copy=malloc(sizeof (*doron_copy));
    doron_copy->player_id=*((int*)copyPlayerId(&(doron->player_id)));
    doron_copy->data_of_player=(Player_data)copyDataPlayer(&(doron->data_of_player));


    doron_copy->data_of_player->number_of_equals=1000;
    doron_copy->data_of_player->number_of_losses=2000;
    doron_copy->data_of_player->number_of_wins=500000;
    doron_copy->player_id=8;
    doron_copy->next=NULL;

    printf("%d\n",doron->player_id);
    printf("%d\n",doron_copy->player_id);
    printf("%d\n",doron->data_of_player->number_of_wins);
    printf("%d\n",doron_copy->data_of_player->number_of_wins);

    //doing free to key element(player id of doron

    freePlayerId(&doron->player_id);
    printf("%d\n",doron->player_id);
    printf("%d\n",doron_copy->player_id);
    printf("%d\n",doron->data_of_player->number_of_wins);
    printf("%d\n",doron_copy->data_of_player->number_of_wins);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You have not shown what `Player_data` and `Player_stats ` are defined to be (I guess they are pointers). But for starters you can only call `free` on the exact pointer that is returned from the allocation functions such as `malloc` . Calling `free` on any other pointer is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: the complete code is long but i think that I understand what do you mean

Comment: Not asking for complete code. Please read the link. It will explain to you what is expected for Stack Overflow debugging questions. If not for this time then at least keep in mind for future questions.

Comment: but the problem is that i do malloc for this element in an other function

Comment: Well, that's code we can't see isn't it? That's why we ask for a minimal reproducible example. We can explain more precisely if you follow the advice to provide an MRE. And no, you can't be mallocing just that element. It is not a pointer. You must be allocating the whole struct. So you can only free the whole struct.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this code.

First, you can only pass to `free` a pointer that was returned from `malloc`, `realloc`, or `calloc`.  You're instead passing in the address of a struct member which would not have been allocated.  Doing so triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Assuming `doron` is what was allocated, if you were to `free` that, it's also not allowed to dereference a pointer to memory that has been freed.  That is also undefined behavior.

Regarding your edit, there's a lot that needs to be fixed.

On this line:

```
doron_copy->player_id=*((int*)copyPlayerId(&(doron->player_id)));
```

You return allocated space containing a copy of `doron->player_id` and dereference that pointer to assign the result to `doron_copy->player_id`.  You loose the pointer that the function returned so this is a memory leak.  This can be replaced with:

```
doron_copy->player_id = doron->player_id;
```

And `copyPlayerId` can be removed entirely, as can `freePlayerId`.

Then you have this:

```
void* copyDataPlayer (void* player_data_to_copy)
```

This function is working with `void *` as the parameter and the return types.  There's no need to use `void *` here because you know the type of what's being passed and what's being returned.  This should be changed to:

```
Player_data copyDataPlayer(Player_data player_data_to_copy)
```

And you can remove the casts in the function:

```
new_copy->number_of_wins=player_data_to_copy->number_of_wins;
new_copy->number_of_equals=player_data_to_copy->number_of_equals;
new_copy->number_of_losses=player_data_to_copy->number_of_losses;
```

And change the call to:

```
doron_copy->data_of_player=copyDataPlayer(doron->data_of_player);
```

This brings up another point.  Although you don't show the definition of `Player_data` and `Player_stats`, it's apparent that these are pointer types.  It's bad style to hide pointers behind a `typedef` as it can mask the fact that you're using a pointer and cause confusion.

Then there's `freeDataPlayer`:

```
void freeDataPlayer(void* player_data_to_free)
{
    Player_data to_free=*(Player_data*) player_data_to_free;
    free(&(to_free->number_of_wins));
    free(&(to_free->number_of_equals));
    free(&(to_free->number_of_losses));
    free(player_data_to_free);
}
```

As with `copyDataPlayer` the parameter should have the type of what you're actually passing in.  As mentioned before, you also don't need to call `free` on the element addresses because they were not returned from `malloc`.  So this function should be:

```
void freeDataPlayer(Player_data player_data_to_free)
{
    free(player_data_to_free);
}
```

Comment: ok so assuming that i did malloc before for the struct player what can I do

Comment: @DoronSlomovits If you assigned the return value of `malloc` to `doron`, then that's what you would pass to `free`, and you can't subsequently dereference `doron`.

Comment: @dbush he is freeing reference to the struct member (read the question - how to free **the part** of a struct). Imo OP needs to start from the C book.

Comment: @0___________ I understand that.  I'm telling him what he *should* do.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can only `free` the memory allocated by the `malloc` family functions
2. You cant free "part of the struct" only the whole allocated block.
3. You cant dereference the freed block.
4. You cant pass to `free` any other reference than returned by `malloc` family functions.